# ag-grid : How to display two columns as single column in the header display?

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have my column defs like below and i have requested to display as Name = First Name + Last Name instead of displaying as two different column in the grid.

[image: Grid Header]

```
var users_column = [
 {
    field: 'FIRST_NAME',
    suppressMenu: true,
}, {
    field: 'LAST_NAME',
    suppressMenu: true,   
},
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your question?

Comment: @LuDeveloper I have accepted as answer.

Comment: nice to answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution I used before:

```
var users_column = [
    {
        headerName: 'Name Surname', field: 'fullname', valueGetter(params) {
            return params.data.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + params.data.LAST_NAME;
        }, suppressMenu: true,
    }
]
```

Comment: Works for Ag Grid with React as well.